# ERROR: Container is unhealthy

Tags: docker

I have installed Sitecore 10 on Docker on my local machine.

Today I am trying to start using following command error message coming on powershell:

**Command**:  `docker-compose.exe up --detach`

**Error**:

```
ERROR: for traefik  Container "b54284cd154a" is unhealthy.

ERROR: for xdbautomationworker  Container "c1a32b355624" is unhealthy.

ERROR: for xdbsearchworker  Container "c1a32b355624" is unhealthy.

ERROR: for cortexprocessingworker  Container "c1a32b355624" is unhealthy.
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Checked the following things:

1. IIS is stopped
2. 8984 port is free
3. Powershell is in Adiminstrator mode
4. Stopped, removed the container and executed the command `docker-compose.exe up --detach` multiple times but no luck.

[image]

Can anyone help me here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I faced this issue too during installation. Try the below steps:

1. Run `docker-compose stop` on Powershell.
2. Run `docker-compose down` on Powershell.
3. Now run `iisreset /stop` on Powershell to make sure that the required ports are free.
4. Now run `docker-compose up -d` on Powershell.

Hoping this solves your issue.

Answer (score 5):

### 1. VPN turned on

Turned on VPN can also cause problem when starting up docker. Try to turn off your VPN and recheck, although I don't know the exact reason why VPN is a problem.

### 2. SQL password

For me changing the `SQL_SA_PASSWORD` in the `.env` solved the problem. Important to run the `clean.ps1` to clean up the already generated database files. Then you can try to rerun the `up.ps1` in case if you are using the [Getting Started template](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html).

Related documentation: https://containers.doc.sitecore.com/docs/troubleshooting

> To resolve, change the SQL password in SQL_SA_PASSWORD to fit the default SQL Server policy. After changing the password in the .env file, remember to clear the mounted SQL data folder after running docker-compose down. You can manually delete its contents, or use a clean script (see the clean.ps1 example in the the Docker Examples repository).

Comment: For me, the environment was up and running. If I change the password in .env file, will it sync with the existing one?

Comment: @Jitendra you are right, you also need to rerun `docker-compose build` and then rerun `docker-compose up --detach`

Comment: @Jitendra it could be also related to VPN connection, try to turn off your VPN while running `.\up.ps1`

Comment: I have the same issue and I also think that enabled VPN might become a root cause of this failure. Unfortunately, I'm unable to turn off VPN due to company policies. I wonder did anybody dig deeper and figure out why exactly VPN might become the root cause of this problem?

Comment: I solved the issue by turning off VPN connection.

Answer (score 3):

I tried all above steps but issue did not resolve.
Best way to understand what actually is causing issue by checking logs.

**Open Visual Studio -> View -> Other Windows --> Containers**

**Check logs for those specific container which are failing would help to resolve issue.**

For me the path of licence file was incorrect in "docker-compose.override.yml" file. After correcting the path it worked.

Comment: Great tip, thank you

Answer (score 3):

The true answer is to check why the health check is failing. This is mostly straightforward...

From your laptop, open Powershell and run "docker container ls". Find the container listed with an unhealthy status.

Open Docker Desktop and select the container that is unhealthy. Note: An unhealthy container may not appear unhealthy within Docker desktop which is why the previous "ls" command is so critical.

Check the logs. It will most likely be running the health check periodically and it will write the attempt to the logs. Here is an example of a failing CM health check:

```
GET /healthz/ready - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT;+Windows+NT+10.0;+en-US)+WindowsPowerShell/5.1.17763.2268 - 500 0 0 35126
```

Notice that the health check is trying to visit /healthz/ready and is receiving a 500 status code. This means our application is experiencing a YSOD but we cannot see it in the Sitecore logs (because Sitecore cannot even start).

Next, issue this command in the shell to view the raw output:

**curl http://127.0.0.1/healthz/ready**

This very quickly showed me that I had a bad reference pushed and I cleaned it up.

A similar approach can be utilized on all container types. Each container may have a slightly different health check, but this approach gets directly to the root of the problem. The previous answers are just guesses on common issues.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the log using the [method](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/29464/12872) provided by [@akash-s](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/3581/akash-s) helped me.

> Open Visual Studio -> View -> Other Windows --> Containers
>
> Check logs for those specific container which are failing would help
> to resolve issue.

For me, I got

```
This container image is out-of-date
It will not have the latest security and bug fixes
Please keep reading for the suggested actions
If you're using Composable Workflow, run either of the following commands:
  docker-compose pull
  docker-compose build --pull
If you're using plain Docker with a custom image, run:
  docker build --pull <the rest your parameters here>
If you're using plain Docker with an image from Artifactory:
  docker pull <Artifactory Host>/<Docker Image>
These commands will re-download more recent versions of the images you use
and resume normal startup of containers
This image expired xx days ago
Exiting ...
```

However, `docker-compose build --pull` doesn't work for me although I'm using docker-compose. `docker pull` the image separately resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to access my container via the browser I get a `This site can’t be reached` response.

The solution was to find the `unhealthy` container's `<GUID>` via `docker ps`.

Once you have that run `docker container inspect <GUID>`

Scrolling down you'll find the `IPAddress`:

```
"Networks": {
    "public-health-ontario_default": {
            ...
            "IPAddress": <CONTAINER IP ADDRESS>
            ...
        }
}
```

Finally, access the error message with `<CONTAINER UP ADDRESS>/healthz/ready`

Answer (score 0):

One of the common and overlooked causes for containers erroring in unhealthy state is computer cpu max-out and isn’t able to process the containers startup, so kill unnecessary/unused processes or set those services to manual while you stop those services and you must see enough cpu power for docker containers to start healthy!

https://navansitecorenotes.blogspot.com/2023/08/everything-running-smoothly-for-around.html